# How can i turn on wifi connection using python?

Tags: python, security

I am working on a project and needs to dynamically enable wifi connection from within my python script. Any suggestion on how i can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set up a Hotspot, you need to enable monitor mode of the WiFi driver.
If you're on linux you can do,

`ifconfig` and `iwconfig` to find the name of WiFi driver/device
and then use one of the air suite package to turn on the monitor mode on that particular driver

```
airmon-ng start <driver name>
```

All these commands can be run using the python subprocess module, which allows you to interact with the linux/windows command line to process output and work out accordingly

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "hello world"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print(p.communicate())

>>>('hello world', None)
```